# Can I add a custom "eligibility check" into a Branch Smart Banner?

Tags: branch.io

I basically need the smart banner to be able to be dynamic. I need to have an input, a button to check eligibility and then a way to download the app if the eligibility check completes. Is this possible with Branch.io?

Answer (score 0):

Custom eligibility check can be added to the smart banner but you can not take input from the smart banner. However there is a workaround, you can take input on your website and then do an eligibility check on smart banner to download the app.

Go through this doc to setup Journey Apps Banner for your website:

https://docs.branch.io/web/journeys/

If you need any more help feel free to reach out to support@branch.io